# Echo Javascript function in PHP to display modal not displaying properly

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

i have a code here which is intended to show a Javascript modal when a textbox is not filled (when send button is clicked it will check for unfilled textboxes and checkbox AND SHOW THE MODAL, if everything is fine, it will send an email...Im working on the textbox first). But I have some problem displaying the modal properly. It seems like when i use display: block it will be shown along with other objects in the form. but when i set it to display: none, nothing is being displayed even after the send button is clicked.

Here's the CSS for modal:

```
 #overlay {
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     text-align:center;
     z-index: 800;
    }
 #overlay div {
     width:800px;
     margin: 100px auto;
     background-color: none;
     border:none;
     padding:15px;
     text-align:center;
    }
 body {
     height:100%;
 width:100%;
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
 overflow:auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="overlay">
<div>
      <img src="images/NoUsername.png" alt="module" style="width:469px; height:345px;">
      <p>[<a href='#' onclick='overlay()'>close</a>]</p>
 </div>
```

I got these codes from http://raventools.com/blog/create-a-modal-dialog-using-css-and-javascript/

Here is the PHP code for checking the textbox:

```
if ($username == "") {

    echo
    "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> 
    function overlay() {
        el = document.getElementById(\"overlay\");
        el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == \"visible\") ? \"hidden\" : \"visible\";
    }</script>";
}
```

I tried using double and single quotations here but nothing happens. I think the problem is in my CSS. Please feel free to edit my code. Thanks in advance for your help guys!

Comment: If you don't want to put that HTML/JS in a different file and include it then you could mix it in using `?> <html> <?php`. Either way you get rid of all those escaped double quotes. Also you could use single quotes around the whole string, but don't do that, it's bad practice to mix PHP and HTML/JS.

Comment: Hi Sergui! I've tried using ?> <html> <?php. But it doesnt seem to work. it's also a requirement in my project to put everything in one file if possible. Can you give some other advice regrading my CSS? thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: or what can i do to call the function if i put this in separate javascript like this?

<script type=\"text/javascript\"> 
    function overlay() {
        el = document.getElementById(\"overlay\");
        el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == \"visible\") ? \"hidden\" : \"visible\";
    }
</script>

Comment: If it's a requirement then use `echo '<script type="text/javascript">... el = document.getElementById("overlay"); ...</script>';` Note the single quotes. Inside you can then use unescaped double quotes. If this does not work then there's an issue with the JavaScript itself.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I think it does work. But my problem now is that my CSS is set to display: none (I alsi tried visibility: hidden)for the modal to be hidden at first. but it doesnt show when the button is clicked even if the z-index is set to 800. hope you can help me with this also. sorry if i have a lot of questions here. thanks :)

Comment: Tried adding a `background-color` property to `#overlay` ? :\ Or am i wrong? :\

Comment: Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/auHDT/ Note that the place where you insert that JS is important. It should be in `<head>`, or in `<body>` but before any hyperlinks with `onclick="overlay()"`.

Comment: You should really study some CSS before going deep into javascript. What you have is a CSS problem: You should have `#overlay {display: none;}` in the stylesheet, then with php print `style="display:block"` in the tag definition. Also, `position` should be `fixed`, shouldn't?

Comment: @user2659523 see this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/auHDT/1/), updated version of Sergiu's code

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, you should study a little more CSS and HTML before going straight through programming like PHP and JavaScript. Your question will probably be flagged as low quality before you can really learn something meaningful from it.

I think the `visibility` attribute isn't suitable for your needs, as it allocates space in the DOM for the element even though it's hidden. I also think you should choose between showing the modal by PHP (server-side) **or** by JavaScript (client-side) as what you're doing now is becoming very confuse, even more for a novice.

I would modify your CSS to:

```
 #overlay {
     display: none; /* hidden if not overwritten by style="" attribute or javascript */
     position: fixed; /* fixed makes more sense here as it doesn't depend on the element's parents, search for it */
 ...
```

IF you choose to show or hide the modal by php, it would be something like

```
<div id="overlay" <?php if ($username == "") echo 'style="display: block;"' ?>>
<div>
      <img src="images/NoUsername.png" alt="module" style="width:469px; height:345px;">
...
```

OR, in my opinion the best approach, making it entirely in JavaScript (**client-side**), without relying on php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function show_modal() {
    el = document.getElementById("overlay");
    el.style.display="block";
  }
  function hide_modal() { // You'll want to use this for the close button
    el = document.getElementById("overlay");
    el.style.display="none";
  }
  function verify_elements() {
    el = document.getElementById("username");
    if (el.value == '') {
      show_modal(); // if the username is '', show'em the modal
      return false; // returning false makes sure the form isn't submited
    }
  }
</script>
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="verify_elements()">
   <input name="username" id="username" value="" />
...
```

I hope it helps to put you in right path. But you should really go step-by-step into this if you really want to learn instead of copy-and-paste forever :D

Best Regards!

Comment: Hi @Leonel! I'm trying your suggestion. where can i exactly place this code? <div id="overlay" <?php if ($username == "") echo 'style="display: block;"' ?>>
<div>
      <img src="images/NoUsername.png" alt="module" style="width:469px; height:345px;"> 

can i place it inside my <?php form or along with other div's in the HTML? thanks a lot!

Comment: it replaces your overlay div. Try to understand the code. And, besides, try the other alternative I gave you!

Comment: thanks Leonel! i am trying them one by one so i could find out and learn more about it. :)

Comment: I really have a hard time finding out what's wrong with my code. I tried the first two codes you suggested. but it didn't work for me. I also tried replacing my javascript with your script while pairing it with the old div but it doesnt work to. is other possible way to make it?

Answer (score -1):

I think that you missed to call the function added to the page:

```
if ($username == "") {

    echo
    "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> 
    function overlay() {
        el = document.getElementById(\"overlay\");
        el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == \"visible\") ? \"hidden\" : \"visible\";
    }
    overlay();
    </script>";
}
```

Also, I believe that the overlay should be hidden by default:

```
#overlay {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
    z-index: 800;
    visiblity: hidden;
}
```

Comment: The function is called when clicking a hyperlink.

Comment: @krasimir - I tried to set use display:block but the problem is that the modal is not showing even when the button is clicked.

Comment: :) That click there is for closing the dialog. The link contains a label *close* and that div is inside the overlay. Sorry @SergiuParaschiv, but please check the code carefully. The idea, as far as I can see is to check if the username is not given to add some js into the page which shows the popup. After that by clicking on close the overlay is hidden again.

Comment: @user2659523 what you mean by *button is clicked*. As I just said above for me it looks like this is a button which close the dialog. You should submit the form, the php code should check if there is a username. If not then it injects that javascript which shows the popup. After that, by clickin on close you actually hide the dialog . That's how you js logic works as well.

Comment: Also you don't need to set display: block, because the div is by default a block element. If you want to use *display* instead of *visiblity* then it is ok. *block* and *none* will toggle the modal dialog.

Comment: He wrote "But my problem now is that my CSS is set to display: none (I alsi tried visibility: hidden)for the modal to be hidden at first. but it doesnt show when the button is clicked even if the z-index is set to 800". His CSS does not contain `display: none;`, it contains `display: block;`. He only posted the close html link here, so I assume his problem is that the overlay does not _close_. I know he talks about opposing situations in the same sentence, but, without clarifications, you don't know that he actually wants it to be hidden by default.

Comment: Ok, @user2659523, please clarify what exactly is the problem. Is in during the hiding or during the showing of the popup/dialog.

Comment: @Krasimir and Sergiu: yes Sergiu is right. what i want is for it to be hidden by default and to be shown after a button click. I'm sorry guys if i was'nt able to express myself clearly.

Comment: @Krasimir and Sergiu:  what i want is for it to be hidden by default. when submit button is clicked it then checks if Username is provided. If not, the modal is then displayed. the user must also be able to close the modal with the "close" link. the I'm sorry guys if i wasn't able to express myself clearly.

Comment: hope you can help me out with this. i'm open to all suggestions. :)

Comment: Ok, then add *visiblity: hidden;* to your *#overlay* styles. This will make model hidden by default. After that add *overlay();* as I showed above. Just below the definition of the function. Leave your field empty and submit the form.